# Estimating the most abundant isotopomer of an isotopic distribution

Tags: probability, chemometrics

i'm trying to pre-estimate the most abundant isotopomers of isotopic distributions.

as a simplified example, picture a molecule with an increasing number of carbons

the natural abundance of carbon's 2 natural isotopes:

```
C12: 0.9893,
C13: 0.0107
```

i can figure out a basic way of estimating the most abundant isotopomer of a distribution of 280 carbons by just multiplying each probability by 280:

```
C12: 277.00399999999996
C13: 2.996
```

and the distribution is like this:

```
C12(277)C13(3): 0.22525042944721088 <-- most abundant isotopomer matches the simple estimate
C12(278)C13(2): 0.22474307454998224
C12(276)C13(4): 0.16871013540851823
C12(279)C13(1): 0.14895543071202053
C12(275)C13(5): 0.10072470876143455
```

which seems to make sense, but this basic estimation of the most abundant isotopomer fails for specific amounts of carbon. the first 200 times this fails:

```
46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,
59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69,  70,  71,
72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,
85,  86,  87,  88,  89,  90,  91, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145,
146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158,
159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171,
172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184,
233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245,
246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258,
259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271,
272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332,
333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345,
346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358,
359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371,
420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432,
433, 434, 435, 436, 437
```

using 264 as an example:

simple estimate:

```
C12: 261.17519999999996
C13: 2.8247999999999998
```

actual distribution:

```
C12(262)C13(2): 0.23726605718494173
C12(261)C13(3): 0.22411525479708402
C12(263)C13(1): 0.16682229513738878
C12(260)C13(4): 0.15816402306474694
C12(259)C13(5): 0.08895427315599433
```

and the simple estimate fails, the estimate would be nice for me because i could calculate the rest of the distribution much quicker.

some kind of pattern is clearly there, but has just a sprinkle of seemingly chaotic behavior when you try and find a deeper pattern, annoyingly difficult to predict. How might I approach this problem? Is there a way to accurately predict the most abundant isotopomer?

is there a non-algorithmic way of knowing how many of each isotope will be present in the most abundant isotopomer population? can it be applied to an element, S for example, that has multiple isotopes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, all those $.99999999$ things must be artifacts of your calculations. Especially when you are starting with four significant figures, you can't expect to wind up with more than four significant figures.

Now, let's look at $264$. The probability of $m$ atoms of C12 and $n=264-m$ atoms of $C13$ is $p_m={264\choose m}(.9893)^m(.0107)^{264-m}$. You want the value of $m$ that maximizes $p_m$.

Let's look at
$$
p_{m+1}/p_m={264!\over(m+1)!(263-m)!}{m!(264-m)!\over264!}{.9893\over.0107}
$$
which simplifies to ${264-m\over m+1}{.9893\over.0107}$ We need to know when this changes from being bigger than one to being smaller than one, so set it equal to one, and solve for $m$. You get $261<m<262$, so you just have to check $m=261$ and $m=262$ to see which gives a bigger result.